# Unable to deploy static content in Magento 2.0

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.0

When I am trying to deploy static content it gives me an error.

```
[Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException]
  Compilation from source:
  frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-m.less
  ._lib-popup-button-close-icon is undefined in /var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/source/_popups.less
```

In ssh and stop processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade Magento to v2.1.0, you may be have this error if you overwrite the **_popups.less** file in your custom theme.

You will need to check the file difference:

**._lib-popup-button-close-icon need to be change with .lib-popup-button-close-icon**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's because the luma theme has an error in the code, in which hasnt been fixed.

goto line 30 of **`_popups.less`**

```
.lib-popup-button-close-icon
```

should be

```
._lib-popup-button-close-icon
```

then on line 23 of the same file remove all those less functions.

Comment: But i was trying to deploy from starting i cleared static folder then run that deploy static content command. when i went to file location i wasn't created yet. but still it gives error for that file

Comment: do you have any solution for that?

Comment: delete the cache, generation, view_preprocessed folders from var and again execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

After updating my magento to v 2.1.0 I started getting the error above. In order to fix it, on the Magento root folder, I've run

```
rm -rf var/
rm -rf vendor/
composer update -vvv
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It fixed my issue.

Cheers,

Renato